# TensorFlow Object Detection API - Validation loss increase while mAP increase aswell?

Tags: validation, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Im trying to retrain a model named: **faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco**

I have only 1 object which i want to detect, it means I have got **1 class only**.
I split my data into train (230 images) and validation (100 images).
After creating csv's and record files, I started to train my model with this config:

```
# Faster R-CNN with Inception Resnet v2, Atrous version;
# Configured for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 8
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 8
        width_stride: 8
      }
    }
    first_stage_atrous_rate: 2
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 17
    maxpool_kernel_size: 1
    maxpool_stride: 1
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000003
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "training/object-detection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 100
  eval_interval_secs: 60
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  # max_evals: 10
  num_visualizations: 100
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "training/object-detection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

**Now, when I open Tensorboard I get a nice loss graphs:**

[Loss Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmeJq.png)

And as you can see training loss (orange) goes down as expected, while val loss (blue) goes down at the begining and then goes up (probably because of overfitting training data).

So far so good, but when i look at mAP and Recall graphs:

[mAP graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoNnw.png)

[Recall graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiWeo.png)

I see mAP goess up as loss goes down, but when loss increase, I would think that mAP will decrease, but it goes up, which i can't understand why.. same for Recall graphs..

My val loss is incresing, but mAP & Recall keep increasing aswell, any idea why?